# Statistics Textbook Answer Explaination?

Tags: probability, statistics

**Question:**

> Suppose there are 10 horses in a race and a bookmaker quotes odds of $r_i$ to $1$ agains horse $i$ winning. Let $p_i = \frac{1}{r_i+ 1}$, $i=1$ to $10$, so each $p_i$ is between $0$ and $1$. Let $\Sigma = p_1 + \cdots + p_{10}$.
>
> a) Do you expect that $\Sigma$ is greater than, smaller than, or equal to $1$? Why?
>
> b) Suppose $\Sigma$ were less than $1$. Could you take advantage of this? How? [*Hint:* By betting on all 10 horses of the race, a bettor can win a constant amount of money, regardless which horse wins.]

a) Equal to 1 because if I pick every horse, the probability that one horse would win is 100%.

b) How can it be less than 1? Then there is a chance that none of the horses in the race wins?

**Actual answers:**

> a) $\Sigma > 1$
>
> b) Yes. In this situation, you can get back more than you bet.

Comment: These are not probabilities.

Comment: If the bookmaker wants to be fair, he might quote accurate odds for each horse.  The bookmaker does *not* need to be fair however and certainly *shouldn't be* if he wants to make money (*as all bookmakers are want to do*).  If the bookmaker were to give the values of $r_i$ in such a way that $\Sigma$ were strictly less than one, then anyone paying attention will bet on every horse simultaneously and win in the long run making the bookmaker lose all of his money.  If the bookmaker were to make it so $\Sigma=1$, then it is fair if people were to bet randomly but he wouldn't expect to earn money.

Comment: The most important observation here is again that the values given to us do not have to accurately reflect the true probabilities.  If the bookmaker wants to expect to make money from people betting, he will certainly make the odds in such a way that $\Sigma>1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no objective way to know the probabilities $p_i$ that the several
horses will win the race. The so-called 'classical' approach might assume
each horse is equally likely to win--which is absurd. The so-called 'frequentist' approach
would require an impossible repeated running of exactly the same race many times.

Bookmaker's odds are based on the 'personal' probabilities of the bettors
on the race. Very roughly, the more money bet on a particular horse the higher
the bookmaker's 'probability' (usually expressed as odds).

However, as mentioned
in the Comment of @JMoravitz, the 'probabilities' implied by the posted
odds are always somewhat inflated to sum to more than $1$ because the bookmaker needs to collect
more (on average) than he/she pays out in order to stay in business.

[Perhaps
one reason for posting *odds* instead of *probabilities* is that it takes
more mental arithmetic than the usual bettor is likely to do, in order to
see the extent to which the bets are slightly 'unfair' to bettors so that the bookmaker
can expect a profit.]